# javascript, error are not displaying from api

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to display errors that comes from the API. 
I'm using Backbone and I'm achieving to display errors if are this type:

```
error: {
    company: [Something is not filled]
}
```

but, if errors comes in this way, are not displaying

```
error: {
    company[0].name: [Can't find name]
}
```

```
function showError(this.model) {
    const errors = this.model.get('error.company');
}
```

Note: error can be: `company[2].lastName: [Can't find last name]`

Comment: Can you clarify, where does your function `showError` live? Inside that method, do you need to populate `errors` with all errors from your model `error` attribute? No matter where it is, it's almost certainly wrong to define the function `function showError(this.model)`.

Comment: Backbone doesn't support nested attributes natively. You should use plugins like backbone deep model. Or are you already using it?